# Javascript Date c`tor returns wrong hours

Tags: javascript

I was creating a new `Date` object like so:

```
new Date(1951, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

> Sun Apr 01 1951 01:00:00 GMT+0300

and as you can see, I wanted the hours to be '0' and instead got '1'.
I know the `Date` object is being affected by timezone, but if I do this:

```
a = new Date(1951, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

> Mon Apr 02 1951 00:00:00 GMT+0300

the timezone remains the same but now the hours portion of the date appears alright.

I would love to get an explanation for this behavior.

and as you can see, I wanted the hours to be '0' and instead got '1'.
I know the Date object is being affeced by timezone, but if I`ll do this:

[image]

the timezone remains the same but now the hours portion of the date appears alright.

would love to get an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried using a wrapper library like Moment.js -- the basic JS Date object is known for being clunky, and MomentJS is good at ironing out a lot of the quirks.

Comment: Does your time zone observe or used to observe daylight saving time around early April?

Comment: Additionally, what browser and version are you using for this testing?

Comment: I am using chrome version 74.0.3729.169. DST is used to be observed around the end of March. I guess it has something to do with it. but I`ll use the same date as the example I gave above but use the year 1952 instead of 1951 it will work fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the reason for this behavior- it is a part of the js spec for the Date object you can read more here https://codeofmatt.com/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/